# best way to continously update time in android

Tags: android

I don't want to use **system time**. and I don't want to get **internet time** once per minute to keep a `textview` in my app up to date. I get time from the server once then increase the time once per second and format it then put it in my textview. after **about 2 hours** the clock is off by **2 minutes**, how can I more accurately update the clock?

```
          new Runnable (){
            public void run() {
            TextView.setText(formatTime(serverTime));
            serverTime+=1;
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    };
```

}

Comment: In any case, you'll still have to depend upon the system clock time even if you have to put a delay for a second (or 1000 ms). So why not use the system clock? Or you should further elaborate that why you do not want to system time as per your scenario!

Comment: If you only want to update the `TextView` upto a certain time in the future, you can use `CountDownTimer` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html.

Comment: @user3472537 Quick look at your profile shows that you haven't accepted a single answer/followed up.  People would be more tempted to answer if you actually acknowledge answer/comments. You should go over [stackoverflow rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`postDelayed(r, t)` does not have any realtime guarantees, it's more or less *post this after at least `t` milliseconds have expired*. Also the total runtime of code after a few calls will probably also amount to a few seconds, resulting in an accumulation of relevant delta.

In such a case, it is probably be to use the system clock to calculate the delta:

```
long savedServerTime = timeFromServer();
long lastReceivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And later:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long delta = (currentTime - lastReceivedTime) / 1000;
TextView.setText(formatTime(serverTime + delta));
```